# HQL gives "unnexpected AST node (" within case clause

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-spatial

This is a **simplified** query which will reproduce the error:

```sql
SELECT 
 CASE 
     WHEN contains(buffer(r.polygon, 0.009), h.latlng) THEN 1 
     ELSE 0 
 END as near 
FROM Region r, House h 
WHERE r.id = 732 AND h.id = 892877180
```

Executing `session.createQuery(hql)` will throw `QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: ( near line 1, column 32`. Column 32 is the first 
opening parentheses which comes right after `contains`.

As the underlying database is MySQL and this HQL happens to be valid MySQL too I tested the exact same query against the MySQL database and it worked fine. So I am assuming the issue relies on the Hibernate Query Language syntax.

I did not find anywhere in the Hibernate documentation stating that using functions inside a `CASE WHEN ... THEN` clause is not supported nor a bug report on this issue though.

Note that when there is no `CASE` clause it works fine:

```sql
SELECT contains(buffer(r.polygon, 0.009), h.latlng) as near 
FROM Region r, House h 
WHERE r.id = 732 AND h.id = 892877180
```

I'm using Hibernate ORM 4.3.11, Hibernate Spatial 4.3 and MySQL 5.6.34 on Ubuntu Linux 18.04.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because the HQL parser expects a relational expression in the `CASE WHEN`-clause, and not just any boolean expression. I suspect this wil work:

```
SELECT 
 CASE 
   WHEN contains(buffer(r.polygon, 0.009), h.latlng) = TRUE THEN 1 
 ELSE 0 
END as near  
FROM Region r, House h 
WHERE r.id = 732 AND h.id = 892877180
```